# Magento2 Product not Display in shopping cart

Tags: magento2.3.7

Magento 2 products do not appear on the cart page They appear blank and i use a custom template if i change to Luma The cart page shows the products without a problem, but if you change to the custom template, the products disappear from the cart page, and this is what the picture shows

[image]

and the path i get file to customize

public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$priceHelper   = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');
$value         = 0;
$priceEmpty    = $priceHelper->currency($value, true, false);
?>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                        $block->getShoppingCartUrl() ?>" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            __('Shopping Cart') ?></span>
        <span class="text-min-cart"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                    __('My Cart') ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty" data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">

            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <span class="counter-number">0</span>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <span class="counter-label">
                <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko i18n: '0' --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'item' --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </span>

            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <span class="price-minicart">
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('subtotalContainer') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <span class="price-minicart">
                <div class="subtotal">
                    <div class="amount price-container">
                        <span class="price-wrapper">
                            <span class="price"><?php echo $priceEmpty; ?></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </span>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()) : ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart" data-role="dropdownDialog" data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
    <?php else : ?>
        <script>
            require(['jquery'], function($) {
                $('a.action.showcart').click(function() {
                    $(document.body).trigger('processStart');
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedConfig() ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-block='minicart']": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                            $block->getJsLayout() ?>
            },
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                                $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Nino, Can you share the logs during loading the cart page? There must be an error & based on that, it will be easy to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple templetes(phtml) files, that are responsible for cart page,
but I have doubt on your form.phtml.
may be some error in your **form.phtml**. so, content not loading.

check code in below file

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[my
> Theme]/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml

one more thing, you can press **CTRL + U** and might be some time error will be disaply in view source only.

hope this helps you. Cheers!!

Comment: I tested and its difficult to say from frontend. but please check file's inside ``app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[my Theme]/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/`` also check if any modification done in ``app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[my Theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml``

Comment: i get file mr @GohilRajesh app/design/frontend/mytheme/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart minicart.phtml one this link download txt https://file.io/JRJDOO8H8Pls and this path app/design/frontend/mytheme/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml file download txt https://file.io/I5cz0DSfiZTs

Comment: minicart.phtml is nothing releated on cart page, minicart is different thing and in checkout_cart_index.xml file I doesn't found any relevent code that can create issue. you have to debug properly, if you dont know magento then hire some one or learn magento first that's only way

Comment: I can see your shopping cart form is not called in shopping cart page.

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed & tested your minicart.phtml file & there is no issue with the same file. The same code is working fine at my end.

The issue is seems to be in other file code. Please check your log file or inspect the same page HTML into the browser. There must be an error & that will help to debug/resolve the issue.

Apart from the above, I found below extra code into your minicart.phtml file as compare to the code PHTML. The code is responsible to broken CSS but the page working/loading fine.

```
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
<span class="price-minicart">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('subtotalContainer') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```